# How to make Emacs not intercept Command-Ctrl-Space, used for Special Characters on macOS?

Tags: key-bindings, input-method, characters

On macOS the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut opens an Emoji picker which can be expanded into a Special Characters picker.

But when I type this shortcut on Emacs in order to input a character, instead of seeing the picker, I see the message

```
<C-s-268632064> is undefined
```

How can I make it show the picker instead?

Comment: Someone will have to check Apple's developer documentation, but I suspect that the application must explicitly ask the OS to display this UI element. If it were truly an OS-wide keyboard shortcut, then Emacs would never see it at all.